# webgrid witha horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using webgrid of asp.net mvc 3.0 razor view to display a dataset. The dataset has 36 columns and so the webgrid goes beyond the visible window. How can I display it within the visble window with a horizontal scrollbar. I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

vks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MVC3 WebGrid support horizontal scrollbars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844655/does-mvc3-webgrid-support-horizontal-scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

You can not have scrollbars directly on webgrid. It is rendered as table anyway. However, you can wrap a div around webgid and apply scrollbars to div. Not a very elegant solution but works fine.